# Powershell using Invoke-DBA query toquery azure SQL is not working

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

We've moved to Azure SQl and I am trying to run a SQL query via powershell my codes is not failing but it is not running anything.

```
Set-DbatoolsInsecureConnection -SessionOnly
#$destcred = Get-Credential XXX
$User = "XXXX"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "XXXXX" -AsPlainText -Force
$destcred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord
 
Connect-DbaInstance 'XXXX' -SqlCredential $destcred

$params = @{
Destination = 'XXXX'
DestinationDatabase = 'X'
DestinationSqlCredential = $destcred
KeepIdentity = $true
KeepNulls = $true
}

 
$Destination = 'XXXX'
$DestinationDatabase = 'XX'
$DestinationSqlCredential = $destcred

$ds = (Invoke-DbaQuery  -SqlInstance $SqlInstance -Database $Database -SqlCredential $destcred -Query "Select count(*) as T from customer"|Select -Expand T -Verbose
)

Write-host $ds
```

Comment: It is failing isn't a helpful problem statement. Are you getting an error? Unexpected results? Undesired behaviour? A server crash? Your fishtank is losing water as a result? *Explain* the problem.

Comment: Make sure your destination and database are correct.  Your query is not returning any data which usually means you are connecting to the wrong database.

Comment: Jdweng - thanks I check and that was exactly the issue

Answer (score 0):

To query Azure SQL using PowerShell  `Invoke-dbaquery`

**Try below sample code:**

```
Set-DbatoolsInsecureConnection -SessionOnly

$User = "username"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$destcred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord
$server = Connect-DbaInstance 'Servername.database.windows.net' -Database pd1 -SqlCredential $destcred

$params = @{
Destination = 'servername.database.windows.net'
DestinationDatabase = 'Databasename'
DestinationSqlCredential = $destcred
KeepIdentity = $true
KeepNulls = $true
}

 
$Destination = 'servername.database.windows.net'
$DestinationDatabase = 'databasename'
$DestinationSqlCredential = $destcred


$ds = (Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $server -Query "select * from tablename" -Verbose)

$ds
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

THanks for the helpful feedback in my panic I had simply not passed in the correct connection string

```
Set-DbatoolsInsecureConnection -SessionOnly
#$destcred = Get-Credential XXXX
$User = "XXXX"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "XXX -AsPlainText -Force  
$destcred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord
 
Connect-DbaInstance 'XXXXX' -SqlCredential $destcred 

$params = @{
Destination = 'XXXX' 
DestinationDatabase = 'XXXX' 
DestinationSqlCredential = $destcred
KeepIdentity = $true
KeepNulls = $true
}

 
$Destination = 'XXXX' 
$DestinationDatabase = 'XXXX'
$DestinationSqlCredential = $destcred
 
 
$1820 = (Invoke-DbaQuery  -SqlInstance $Destination -Database $DestinationDatabase -SqlCredential $destcred -Query "
```

THe SQLinstance destination and database in set in the @{ Parameter section of the code